# value in dataframe need to be matched with another and then add another colume based on the result

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a use case where i have two dataframes
for example below, first dataframe value need to be matched with second dataframe, which is done by isin
df3=df1['Values2'].isin(df2.Values) and this return a true dataset.
However, requirement is to create third dataframe with matched values and its name added.

```
Name    Values                  
xyz    12.34.45                 
abc    34.56.78                 
pqr    12.12.13                 
asd    15.12.14                 
                        
                        
Values2   Score  Address    Group   Remark  Grade   
10.11.13    10   fdsg       A       Q1      A+  
34.56.78    8    fdg        B       Q2      B+  
12.12.13    4    fdg        C       Q4      A++ 
15.12.14    7    fdgzdg     D       Q3      A   
10.12.13    5.5  kjklj      E       Q9      B+  
                        
                        
                        
Values2     Name        Score   Address Group   Remark  Grade
10.11.13    not found   10      fdsg        A   Q1      A+
34.56.78    abc         8       fdg         B   Q2      B+
12.12.13    pqr         4       fdg         C   Q4      A++
15.12.14    asd         7       fdgzdg      D   Q3      A
10.12.13    not found   5.5     kjklj       E   Q9      B+
```

Comment: Please post your two dataframes as text not image.

Comment: i have changed the picture with values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input data (partial):

```
>>> df1
  Name    Values
0  xyz  12.34.45
1  abc  34.56.78
2  pqr  12.12.13
3  asd  15.12.14

>>> df2
    Values2  Score
0  10.11.13   10.0
1  34.56.78    8.0
2  12.12.13    4.0
3  15.12.14    7.0
4  10.12.13    5.5
```

Merge two dataframes on "left":

```
>>> pd.merge(df2, df1, left_on="Values2", right_on="Values", how="left") \
      .drop(columns="Values")

    Values2  Score Name
0  10.11.13   10.0  NaN
1  34.56.78    8.0  abc
2  12.12.13    4.0  pqr
3  15.12.14    7.0  asd
4  10.12.13    5.5  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Corralien, this worked perfectly.